# CORS Header: Where to put it? And what URL to put?

Tags: javascript, cors

I have a website that fetches some JSON data from a heroku server I set up. I'm getting a CORS error and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

I am requesting it from a url, let's say, https://www.example.com/content/?id=12345

In my heroku endpoint, I have code that looks like this:

```
res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ["https://www.example.com"]);
```

But I still get this error that says the origins don't match:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 
https://mysterious-hamlet-72124.herokuapp.com/5iucwuFiaK1nJqWwfSHt.
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘https://example.com’).
```

Right now, I just set it to:

```
res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ["*"]);
```

and it works, but I'd like to know how to do it right.

Edit: Thanks for catching my typo...Dang do I feel stupid. I forgot to add "www" on my server-side, like the comments below said.

Comment: `https://www.example.com` indeed does not match `https://example.com`

Comment: You said your requesting URL is `https://www.example.com`, but your error says `https://example.com`. Looks like your forgot the `www`, even though you've included it in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
can you try below code in server side and it will resolve cors issue

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'example.com');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
}

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(allowCrossDomain);
});
```

Comment: can you get away with `example.com` in the origin without specifying protocol?

Comment: you can set like ---> res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

Comment: @JaromandaX in this I find it best to just try yourself and learn the behavior. I would be interested to know the answer too

Comment: I know that you can use `*`, but can you put just the domain without `http[s]://` - never seen that in action or in any documentation

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka - why would I try to do something that is not documented

Comment: I think `app.configure` has been removed in Express v4.

Comment: @JaromandaX I refered to www.example.com vs just example.com (The documentation depends on the web server or browser ) and trying this, besides learning the behavior, would have help u catch your error.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka - my error? I think you have me mistaken for someone else - I don't have an error, vsquare does!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cors npm package

and add this code to your app.js (or whatever is your main file)

```
const cors = require("cors");
...
app.use(
 cors({
  origin: "Your front-end domain",
 })
);
```

this works for me.

But if you want to know more about what CORS is I suggest you [Mozilla developer guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#:%7E:text=Cross%2DOrigin%20Resource%20Sharing%20(CORS)%20is%20a%20mechanism%20that,resources%20from%20a%20different%20origin.&text=The%20CORS%20mechanism%20supports%20secure,transfers%20between%20browsers%20and%20servers.)